# Тестирование RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, espresso

```
onData(anything())
.inAdapterView(withId(R.id.recyclerview))
.atPosition(position)
.onChildView(withId(R.id.minus))
.perform(click());
```

C `ListView` работал норм. заменил `ListView` на `RecyclerView` выдает ошибку `android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id:`

Comment: как минимум, потому что в RecyclerView нет AdapterView

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался,

```
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position, 
    clickChildViewWithId(R.id.minus)));

public static ViewAction clickChildViewWithId(final int id) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Click on a child view with specified id.";
            }

            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                View v = view.findViewById(id);
                v.performClick();
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В данной реализации recyclerView некорректно 'присутствие' `onData`, так как они вместе не работают.
`onData` - предназначена для AdapterViews like ListView, GridView, Spinner, и т д. 
Вижу что Вы разобрались в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585346/211117), но для подкрепления и для будущих читателей данного вопроса приложу [офф.документацию](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/index.html), которая подскажет как и с чего лучше начать.